# Order of matrix multiplications in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glViewport(0/*left*/, 0/*botton*/, 200/*width*/, 200/*height*/); //T4   
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
glLoadIdentity();   
gluPerspective(90 /*fov*/, 1/*aspect*/, 1/*fp*/, 1000/*bp*/); //T3
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity();     
gluLookAt(0/*eyex*/,0/*eyey*/,0/*eyez*/, 0/*lax*/,0/*lay*/,-1/*laz*/, 0/*upx*/,1/*upy*/,0/*upz*/); //T2
glTranslatef(-15.0, -10.0, -49.0); //T1
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex4f(0, 0, -1, 1);
glEnd();
```

Given this code, in what order does the matrix multiplication happen? What do I have to know to follow and verify the calculations on paper?

I suspect to following order, but haven't figured out a way to verify it:
v=[0,0,-1,1]

```
T4 * T3 * T2 * T1 * v
```

Is this correct?

Comment: So viewport is just rescale and tranlate from -1..+1, to 0..200 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly correct, however `glViewport (...)` by itself does not define a matrix. It is a simple bias and scale operation. It defines the total width, height and offset in X and Y. There is another component you are missing, which is the depth range.

The multiplication occurs in that order, but since these are column-major matrices and post-multiplied, you conceptually start on the right and then work your way to the left. Cross out `T4` because it alone is not a matrix, and the end result of all this is a clip-space vertex coordinate. You still need to divide `v.xyz` by `v.w` and then do the viewport transformation to fully replicate what GL does.

You **can** implement the viewport transform using a matrix, but you also need to factor in `glDepthRange (...)` which biases and scales the Z coordinate from NDC space to window space.

Here is what such a matrix would look like:

[image: Row-major viewport matrix]

The whole process is discussed in better detail here, under [***4.1  Coordinates Transformation***](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_BasicsTheory.html#zz-4.).

Comment: @Kalevi: There are a couple of things wrong on the site I linked to, particularly the discussion of the clip volume. In GL we have an NDC volume of [-1,1] in all directions. In D3D it is [-1,1] in XY and [0,1] in Z. [This site](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) is more accurate, but not nearly as visual and lacks the discussion of a viewport transformation matrix (which is also wrong for OpenGL, as Y is not inverted like that).

Comment: @Kalevi: Thus, it should be `h/2` **not** `-h/2`, `(maxZ-minZ)/2` and `maxZ + minZ/2` **not** `minZ`. I will try to find a better article to link to tomorrow. Feel free to leave me a comment if you have trouble actually implementing what I discussed.